# Niagara Falls joke?

Tags: armada

> "Really" Cruz said, laughing. "Is she from Canada? The Niagara Falls area, perhaps?"

I am sure there is some subtext here. But I have no idea what I am missing.

Comment: This could really use some extra context around it.

Answer (score 4):

This is just an instance of the [girlfriend in Canada trope/joke](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GirlfriendInCanada).

A character will purport to have a girlfriend in some distant state or country, making it impossible, or at least difficult for anyone to verify the story, or to conclusively disprove it.

When used in a work, "nerd" characters are often the ones claiming to have a girlfriend in Canada.

In *Armada*, Zack is regaling his friends with a story which his friends find unlikely. Not only was he supposedly at Crystal Palace, but he met a "super-hot mech driver" who kissed him, all within one day.

> “If you must know,” I said, “that super-hot mech driver I met at Crystal Palace showed me how to do it. She also kissed me, FYI.”
>
> “Really?” Cruz said, laughing. “Is she from Canada? The Niagara Falls area, perhaps?”

Comment: @armadillo Niagra Falls is a place commonly used in the trope, often because a person supposedly vacationed there.

Comment: Seriously, don't overthink this.